# Ajax loading gif when page load c# web form

Tags: c#, ajax, loading

I am trying to create a loading `gif` on my page while processing data.

Here is what I tried so far:

HTML markup:

```
 <div id="loadingImg" style="display: none;" class="m-auto mt-9">
     <img src="load.gif" height="120" width="240" />
 </div>
```

Code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public void getData(){
 //I got my DataTable data from Database
 gridview1.DataSource = dt;
 gridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And this is my Ajax loading code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#loadingImg').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/mypages.aspx/getData",
                method: 'get',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loadingImg').hide();
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

        });
```

But I am getting the loading.gif after the page successfully load.
How to display loading a `gif` while page is processing those `void getData()`?

Answer (score 1):

At ajax request to a C# method we normally use **success** and **error** function. We also use a **complete** function as well. The difference between success and complete function is-

`.success()` only gets called if your webserver responds with a 200 OK HTTP header - basically when everything is fine.

On the other hand,

`.complete()` will always get called no matter if the ajax call was successful or not.

> $('#loadingImg').hide();

In your code take the gif hide function inside the success function. Then it will work properly as you expect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#loadingImg').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/mypages.aspx/getData",
                method: 'get',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loadingImg').hide();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });

        });
```

- https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/
- https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/